# how to Import an image in React with parcel-bundle

Tags: image, reactjs, jsx, parceljs

I want to add an image with a require statement.

But I got the following error:

> Cannot find module '../../../assets/skillName.png'

I build app using `parcel-bundle` and I don't use `webpack`.
The path to the image is correct, because if I use a static link, it works well:

```
<img src={require(`../../../assets/skillName.png`)}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
{Object.keys(this.props.skillset).map((skill) => {
    let source = require(`../../../assets/${skill}.png`);
     return (
       <div key={skill}>
         <img src={source}/>
        </div>
     )
   })}
```

Comment: try adding your code to jsfiddle or sandbox it would be easier to debug

Comment: I found my mistackes. I didn't add improt for all images in this component. Now it works

Comment: Then mark it as a resolved answer. It confused me, I though the solution does not work, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/smilesaayush/pen/oyzMZd

I did it this way and it worked for me, try not using require, and give absolute url in image source, which I think in your case should be - `window.location.host` + relative url.

```
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {[100, 200].map((len) => {
             return (
               <div key={len}>
                 <img src={`https://placeimg.com/${len}/${len}/any`}/>
                </div>
             )}
           )}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can control the steps:

1.really skillName.png image place the assets folder.

2.You can remove skillName name from json data.then see other images.if you can show other image, your image name is incorrect.
because your code is correct but can be small problem.